# How to convert Time string in UTC to CST in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I need to convert timestamp String in UTC TZ format to CST TZ format as shown in here "2019-01-02T11:53:59.269-05:00"

So basically i need the output of this query with SYSTIMESTAMP replaced with time String in UTC TZ Format.
 select TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP ,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') CREATEDTIME from dual;

I tried lot of stuff but getting errors

select TO_CHAR( to_timestamp('2019-01-02 11:53:59.759', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH')  ,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') CREATEDTIME from dual

Error
ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Could you please help me write the correct SQL query.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your input is on 2 January 2019 at 11:53 AM - in what time zone? The output you say you want has the same date and time-of-day as the input; if you are converting from UTC to CST, that won't be the case, will it? Best to show the input EXACTLY as you have it (most likely it doesn't have double-quotes around it) and its data type (is it a string?) and the desired output (a string? Certainly not with double-quotes around it, unless that is part of your problem requirement).

Comment: Please also see [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `TSTZ`, you can select at a different time-zone.
Below are some examples for daylight- and standard-time.

Standand-Time:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-01-02T16:53:59.269 UTC',
                       'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR') AT TIME ZONE 'AMERICA/CHICAGO',
               'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM')
    AS CENTRAL_TIME
FROM  DUAL;
```

Result:

```
CENTRAL_TIME
2019-01-02T10:53:59.269-06:00


1 row selected.
```

And a daylight-savings example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-04-02T17:35:52.136 UTC',
                               'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR') AT TIME ZONE 'AMERICA/CHICAGO',
               'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM')
    AS CENTRAL_TIME
FROM  DUAL;
```

Result:

```
CENTRAL_TIME
2019-04-02T12:35:52.136-05:00


1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however my requirement is to get the TS in CST TZ in the format 2019-04-02T11:53:59.269-05:00   Here -05:00 or -6:00 based on daylight savings.     So i read UTC Timestamp string from flat file,  i need to use it in SQL query to convert it in to CST TZ in the format mentioned and then pass it to another program which validates the format and process the data.

Comment: Thanks @PrateekShrivastava.  Ok will edit to that format.